MUI Autocomplete field clears after onSubmit
I'm working on a React application using react-hook-form and @mui/material, and I have a form that includes an Autocomplete component for selecting multiple values. The issue I'm facing is that when I submit the form, the value of the Autocomplete field resets to its initial state.
onSubmit = { handleSubmit((data) => {
    onSearch(createSearchData(data));
})}

<Controller
    control={control}
    name="industries"
    render={(renderProps) => (
        <Autocomplete
            multiple
            filterSelectedOptions
            options={industriesValues}
            onChange={(_, newValue) =>
                renderProps.field.onChange(newValue)
            }
            value={renderProps.field.value}
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    label="Industries"
                    helperText={renderProps.fieldState.error?.message}
                    error={Boolean(renderProps.fieldState.error?.message)}
                />
            )}
        />
    )}
/>  

I've tried to use reset with value stored in another variable inside onSubmit but it doesn't look like it has any effect. In the same form, I have the FormTextFields which don't reset after triggering onSubmit so I guess the issue is somewhere in Controller.

Since you're using Controller to manage the Autocomplete's state, the reset might be happening due to re-renders or because the state isn't being updated correctly.
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    onSearch(createSearchData(data));
    // You can use reset here if you need to reset the form
    reset(getValues());
}


<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="industries"
        render={({ field, fieldState }) => (
          <Autocomplete
            multiple
            filterSelectedOptions
            options={industriesValues}
            onChange={(_, newValue) => field.onChange(newValue)}
            value={field.value}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                label="Industries"
                helperText={fieldState.error?.message}
                error={Boolean(fieldState.error?.message)}
              />
            )}
          />
        )}
      />
    </form>


I don't want to reset values to the default state, I want them to be kept after triggering onSubmit, and this doesn't seem like a solution to me - it didn't change anything I think. In the same form I have another fields which are just FormTextField values and those fields don't reset it's state after submitting.
